# Mozilla Observatory does not recognize my CSP header

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, content-security-policy

I checked my website on https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze.html?host=michael.walter.berlin and it is permamently saying that I did not implement a CSP-Header. I implemented it, which can be seen in the headers in Google Chrome and even on the website of Mozilla.

My .htaccess is setting the headers and looks like this:

```
[...]
Header set X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;script-src 'self' https://oss.maxcdn.com;"
[...]
```

The output from mozilla's observatory is

```
X-Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;script-src 'self' https://oss.maxcdn.com;
```

The CSP-Header is recognized from my browser and shows errors in the console when I am violating these rules.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you've added `X-Content-Security-Policy` instead of `Content-Security-Policy`

Comment: OMG. Thank you very much. I was looking for hours at this and did not see it.